# WordPress, Contact Form 7 - One form in two places on the same page, with two different redirections

Tags: wordpress, redirect, conditional-statements, contact-form-7

I have a simple page with one and the same Contact Form 7 form in two places, at the top and at the bottom. The client requires a redirect after form submission, but the two forms should lead to two different 'thank you' pages. I wasn't able to find any clue as to how this is possible.

Comment: Duplicate the original form so it's still the same form but you can define unique redirect paths. You can do this straight from the Contact Form 7 interface.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought of this, but I would like to avoid it. Another client has 8 different sites with 5 identical forms on each site, so imagine what maintenance nightmare that is. My question is whether it's possible to have two different redirects for one and the same form.

Comment: How are you redirecting the form? External Javascript, adding the JS under "Additional Settings?" or some other way?

Comment: I'm using the `Additional Settings` field, but I don't mind doing it any other way, if only it worked. At this moment I'm out of ideas how this could be done.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to do this from the same form. They're different forms with different behavior. You're going to need to duplicate them (since you're using CF7)

Comment: mevius you're not right. That is one exact same form, meant to do the exact same thing. Having multiple forms with the identical configuration and purpose would make no sense at all. However, I did come up with a solution of my own for this problem.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ Please post your answer, and select it as correct.